# "sick" Label in Inductor Datasheet

Tags: pcb-design, inductor, datasheet, footprint

I was looking through the following datasheet for a Sumida inductor:

http://products.sumida.com/products/pdf/CDR105,105B.pdf

I am creating a library component for a part in this series and when working on the land pattern I noticed a label titled "sick" in the datasheet, pointing to an area between the two pads:

[image]

I have never seen this before. Is it some obscure term to reference a part of a land pattern? Might it be an abbreviation for something? Or perhaps is it just a word used internally at Sumida? I'm suspecting the third option but am very curious to know if anyone has seen this reference before and can help to define it in this context.

Comment: Looks like a really bad translation to english.  Normally this might be part of solder mask and a mask is what people wear to isolate sick germs

Comment: Maybe misspelling of silk? (silk screen)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That is a great theory!

Comment: @Ayhan That was my first though too but is probably not the case for two reasons: 1) Silkscreen is rarely called out in land patterns, especially not between pads, and 2) the same label is shown in multiple places in the datasheet

Answer (score 5):

It really looks like they misspelled it. If you compare it to a similar [datasheet](http://products.sumida.com/products/pdf/CR75.pdf) you see they name it silk screen! And in another [datasheet](http://products.sumida.com/products/pdf/CDRH74.pdf) they call it solder resist. So they are not very consistent in the datasheets.

Due to this and common practice and the IPC norm we can conclude that it needs to be solder mask!

Comment: No one should be using screen printing between SMD pads. They should be using solder mask.  (-1)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 the answer was edited to rectify the issue you mentioned, so you can remove the downvote and downvote the manufacturer for putting out bad datasheets - I would have expected better from a Japanese brand...

Comment: Once again if it was a misspelling I wouldn't expect it to show up multiple times in the datasheet, unless it's a language-related issue. Still giving a +1 though considering the "silk screen" label in the other datasheet.